# What are the conditions on $a, b, c$ so that $ax*|x|+bx+c$ is bijective

Tags: functions

a,b,c is real and a≠0

I would like to find the conditions on a, b, c so that

$f(x)=ax|x|+bx+c$

is bijective.

I tried to expand the module to make 2 functions :

f<sub>1</sub>(x)=ax<sup>2</sup> +bx +c  for x≥0

f<sub>2</sub>(x)=-ax<sup>2</sup> +bx +c for x<0

and then i went graphic and separate it in 2 cases for :

1.b<sup>2</sup> -4ac ≥0 (when f<sub>1</sub>(x) has 2 solutions)

2. b<sup>2</sup> -4ac <0 (when f<sub>1</sub>(x) has 1 solutions)

And in case1 i got that c<0 and a>0

case2: i got that c>0 and a>0

I got stuck because at the end of the book  is a*b≥0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the quickest way is using monotonicity.

Indeed taking the derivative we get

$$f'(x)=2a|x|+b$$
which indeed is always positive, respectively negative, if $a$ and $b$ share the same sign.

Comment: I like this answer, but it should also include $b=0$ as a solution.

Comment: Indeed you are right, $a=0$ or $b=0$ are special cases where the denomination "same sign" does not really apply. As these are quite simple, I'll avoid including the discussion in the answer but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a purely algebraic way to solve this.

As you do, split the function into the positive and negative portions; at $x=0$, we know $y=c$.

On $\Bbb R^+ = \{x\in\Bbb R \ | \ x > 0\}$, $y = ax^2 + bx + c$. We know that the vertex is at $x_v = -b/2a$, and the function is monotonic on either side of the vertex. The function will thus be monotonic on $\Bbb R^+$ if and only if $x_v \notin \Bbb R^+$. Thus, we require $-b/2a \leq 0$, i.e. $b=0$ or $b$ and $a$ have the same sign -- we'll call this condition $(\star)$.

A similar argument on $\Bbb R^- = \{ x\in\Bbb R \ | \ x < 0\}$ follows. Here, $y = -ax^2 + bx + c$, so $x_v = b/2a$. We require $b/2a \geq 0$, and thus (again) we find that $b=0$ or $b$ and $a$ have the same sign, a.k.a $(\star)$.

Thus, the function is monotonic (and thus injective) iff $(\star)$.

To get from monotonic to surjective, we just need that it is unbounded above and below, which is simple enough to argue here (hint: quadratics are unbounded, and the sign flips over the origin).

With that, we have that the function is bijective iff $(\star)$.

As a final point, note that $(\star)$ is equivalent to $ab\geq 0$.